# Metric on $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology

Let $p\in \Bbb R^2$ and

$$d: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R \\
     d(x,y) = \begin{cases}\lVert x-y \rVert &\text{, if x and y are on a straight line through p}\\\rVert x-p\lVert + \lVert p-y\rVert &\text{, else.}\end{cases}$$

Is $d$ a metric on $\Bbb R^2$?

I think that metrics are generally continuous but $d$ is not: As $y$ approaches $x$, we see that $d(x,y)$ approaches $2\lVert x-p \rVert$. But $d(x,x)=0$

Symmetry and positive definiteness are satisfied but I can't find a counterexample for the triangle inequality though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a metric**

The fact is that a metric $d$ is continuous for the topology ***induced*** by $d$.

The proof of the fact that $d$ is a metric:

The only thing more tricky to show is the triangular inequality, now, the worst case is when $x,z$ are not co-linear with $p$ (because if they are co-linear with $p$, then we know that the usual metric *is* a metric):

$\displaystyle{d(x,z)= ||x-p||+||z-p||= ||x-p||+||y-p||-||y-p||+||z-p||+||y-p||-||y-p||=d(x,y)+d(y,z)-2||y-p||\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)}$

where this is in the worst case where $x,y,z$ are not co-linear with $p$

Let's take now $x,y$ co-linear with $p$, then we have:

$d(x,z)=||x-p||+||z-p||\leq_{{\text{because of the usual triangle inequality}}}||x-y||+||z-p||+||y-p||\leq_{\text{here z,y are not co-linear with p}} ||x-y||+d(y,z)=d(x,y)+d(y,z)$

finally, if $x,y,z$ are all co-linear with $p$, we have:

$d(x,z)=||x-z||\leq||x-y||+||y-z||$

There are other cases, for example if $x,z$ are co-linear with $p$, then we have that $y$ can be not co-linear with them, but this is really an analogue case of the ones above.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the best way to prove $d(x,z)\le d(x,y)+d(y,z)$ is to break it into cases:

1. $x,z,p$ are colinear, and

   - (a)  $y$ is also colinear with $x,z,p$
   - (b) $y$ is not  colinear with $x,z,p$
2. $x,z,p$ are not colinear, and

   - (a) $y$ is colinear with $x,p$,
   - (b) $y$ is colinear with $z,p$,
   - (c) neither of the above holds.

There are really only four cases here, since 2(a) becomes 2(b) by interchanging $x$ and $z$.